How to Isolate my Power Supply Circuit from Mains?
I'm building a lab bench power supply and I want to power it from mains voltage.
My plan is to buy this transformer to go from 120VAC to 12VAC, then send the 12VAC through a rectifier, and then finally through the rest of the circuit I designed.
My question is that I'm not sure if the transformer will isolate the rest of the circuit from mains.

Could I ask why you think it wouldn't provide isolation? Transformers are generally used to provide isolation, and the one you linked is pretty standard. The two separate coils have no direction conduction path, so as long as you don't do anything to tie the primary side to the secondary, it will be isolated. There are probably other safety steps that you should take when designing with mains, and it's not my area of expertise.

@cEEa  When I looked online to purchase the components I needed for my project, there was a section of transformers that were classified as "isolation transformers". I'm confused because I was under the assumption that transformers isolate the primary and secondary side by default.

Ah, okay. Most standard transformers you come across will be isolated. An example of a transformer type which isn't isolated is an autotransformer. But if you look in the datasheet for the part you sent, the schematic drawing shows two separate coils which would suggest they are isolated. Additionally, there is a "HiPot" test specification. This stands for "high potential" and is used to measure the insulation between the coils. The fact that it has a input to output and input/output to core measurement also means that they have electrically isolated the input/output/core from eachother.

@cEEa I see, Thank you!

@MXVG Isolation transformer is a term used for a 1:1 transformer, where you are only interested in galvanic separation, not change of voltage.

Yes, that transformer will provide isolation. It is tested as follows (probably for 60 seconds):

Hipot: 1500VAC – Input to Output, Input & Output to Core

Tranformers sold as "isolation transformers" are typically something like 120:120 VAC and provide isolation (but maybe no voltage change) from input to output, for (more) safely powering things being tested, for example.
There are transformers which do not provide any isolation but do change the voltage- autotransformers (often used to change 120VAC to 240VAC or vice versa, and variable transformers (aka variacs).
